# excel and sql queries through different subs or functions

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have an excel sheet which i use with an access database. I want to open the database and use different sub routines with different queries.
However i don't know hot to publically assign an variable to use the database so i have to create the connection within each subroutine and open and close this.

I have a fealing that this must be able to do smarter so i don't have the same code written all over it.

I open the database with the following code and have to do this over and over for every query:

```vb
Public Sub copy_to_sql()

    Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command

    Dim strMDB As String

    strMDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\klantserverinfo.accdb"
    ' Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" & strMDB
    Cn.Open

    '--- Do some queries like

    SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM database"

    Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
    Cmd.CommandText = SqlQuery
    Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    Set Rs.Source = Cmd
    Rs.Open    

    Cn.close
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to do this better?

Ps, I use Office 2010 and the database used is an access 2010 database