# Multiple SQL query ouput in one Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hope some one will help me with the problem i am facing. The issue is I am having difficulties in getting multiple SQL queries output in same excel worksheet.

Through below code i am able to get output of one/ single SELECT query output with column header. Now i want to display more than one SELECT query output in the same worksheet.

code ---

```
Sub databases()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sSQL1 As String


sSQL1 = "SELECT SUM(number_submitted)as NUMBER_SUBMITTED," & _
"MGR_GRP_ID,SERVICE_CI_ID,LOCATION_ID from CHANGE_REQUEST_ENUM_F where              ENUM_FIELD_CD=11834 and ENUM_VALUE in (10,11)" & _
"group by MGR_GRP_ID,SERVICE_CI_ID,LOCATION_ID"

'sSQL2 = "select * from change_request_f"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Sheets("sheet4").Select
Selection.ClearContents

cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; UID=USERID;PWD=PASSWORD;Initial catalog=BMCDI_DWH;Data             Source=vw-pun-atm-qa26"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sSQL1, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
'check content of rs
If rs.EOF Then
MsgBox ("record set is empty. rs.EOF = " & rs.EOF)
Else
MsgBox ("total records: " & rs.RecordCount)
Range("A1").Select
For Each qf In rs.Fields
Range("a1").Offset(0, coloffset).Value = qf.Name
'Range("a1").Offset(1, 0).Value = qf.Name
coloffset = coloffset + 1
Next qf
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [I have answered a very similar question already, please click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436006/excel-and-sql-queries-through-different-subs-or-functions/16436388#16436388)

Answer (score 0):

I would split this out into another sub.

```
 Sub writeRs(rs as ADODB.Recordset, startRange as Range)
 'All your code here to place the recordset
 'The only change would be for the use of startRange
 'This you would pass the upper left cell that you want the recordset to be written to.

 End Sub
```

Then you can use two recordset objects. `rs1` and `rs2` and call your sub

```
 rs1.Open sql1, cn...
 rs2.Open sql2, cn...

 ''Check for empties

 writeRs rs1, Range("A1")
 writeRs rs2, Range("A10")
```